# update unidirectional one to one problem

Tags: grails, groovy, associations, hbase

I have two domain classes:

```
class Domain1 {

  String val11
  String val12
  Domain2 domain2

  static constraints = {
  }
}

class Domain1Controller{

  /**
   * Create new Domain1 entity instance
   */
  def create = {
    def domain1 = new Domain1()
    def domain2 = Domain2.get(params.domain2)
    if(domain2!=null){
      domain1.domain2 = domain2
    }

    domain1.properties=params
    domain1.save(flush: true)

    String strJson = (domain1 as JSON)
    render strJson
  }

  /**
   * Update Domain1 entity fields values
   */
  def update = {
    Domain1 domain1 = Domain1.findById(params.id)
    params.remove("id")
    if (domain1 != null) {
      domain1.properties=params
      domain1.save(flush:true)
      String strJson = (domain1 as JSON)
      render strJson
    }
  }
}

class Domain2 {

  String val21
  String val22

  static constraints = {
  }
}

class Domain2Controller{

  /**
   * Create new Domain2 entity instance
   */
  def create = {
    def domain2 = new Domain2()          
    domain2.properties=params
    domain2.save(flush:true)
    String strJson = (domain2 as JSON)
    render strJson
  }

  /**
   * Update Domain2 entity fields values
   */
  def update = {
    Domain2 domain2 = Domain2.findById(params.id)
    params.remove("id")
    if (domain2 != null) {
      domain2.properties=params
      domain2.save(flush: true)
      String strJson = (domain2 as JSON)
      render strJson
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is when I create associated objects,I cannot update domain1.

I think reason maybe in `save()` method... maybe not

Is there anyone who know why I cannot update Domain1 properties ?

I use grails-1.3.2 and hbase-0.2.4 plugin.

P.S. hbase does not understand mapping..

Thanks for help.

Comment: replace `save(flush: true)` with  `save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` then post the exception that is thrown (if any)

Comment: @Don I have replaced save(flush: true) with save(flush: true, failOnError: true)...It did not throw any exception and it did not update domain1 object..

Comment: I have tried to replace save(flush:true) with save(flush: true, failOnError: true, deepValidate: false) and got NullPointerException exception:                                ERROR gorm.SavePersistentMethod  - Cannot get property 'class' on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'class' on null object
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.getProperty(NullObject.java:56)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:156)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.ca
//--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the exception you provided in the comment, I think the problem is the line where You call `domain1.properties=params`. Domain properties map contain some specific keys, and when you assign `params` map to it, those specific (ie. `class` property here) are missing, so GORM cant access them.

Use bind() method to bind parameter values to your domain object this way:

```
    def domain1 = new Domain1()
    bind(domain1, params)
    def domain2 = Domain2.get(params.domain2)
    if(domain2!=null){
      domain1.domain2 = domain2
    }

    domain1.save(flush: true)
```

Comment: jjczopek after explicity seting domain2 value to domain1 ( domain1.domain2 = domain2) it would work, but i do not want one more time send request to db.